# Google Analytics API insufficient_scope error

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

all. I am currently working on a go project that requires me to connect to Google Analytics API v3. I am authenticating using service account method. I am pretty sure that I am able to authenticate but I am getting "insufficient_scope" error. I am not sure what's going on here.

My config struct

```
config := &jwt.Config{
        Email:settings.Client_email,
        PrivateKey:[]byte(settings.Private_key),
        Scopes: []string{
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly",
        },
        TokenURL: google.JWTTokenURL,
    }
```

The response header

```
Cache-Control:[private, max-age=0] 
X-Xss-Protection:[1; mode=block] 
Alt-Svc:[quic=":443"; p="1"; ma=604800] 
Date:[Fri, 23 Oct 2015 17:45:13 GMT] 
X-Content-Type-Options:[nosniff] 
X-Frame-Options:[SAMEORIGIN] 
Server:[GSE] 
Alternate-Protocol:[443:quic,p=1] 
Vary:[Origin X-Origin] 
Content-Type:[application/json; charset=UTF-8] 
Www-Authenticate:[
  Bearer realm="https://accounts.google.com/", 
  error=insufficient_scope,
  scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics"
] 
Expires:[Fri, 23 Oct 2015 17:45:13 GMT]
```

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out. I just needed to add client email to Google Analytics account.
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009702?hl=en#Add